# Create bootable USB stick on macOS - stick does not appear as bootable

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I would like to erase the existing operating system and install Ubuntu on my Macbook6.1.

I am following [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0) to create a bootable USB device.
But my USB stick does not appear as bootable device in Apple's 'Startup Manager' on step 7.

I set the format to MS-DOS (FAT) and the scheme to GUID Partition Map when preparing my USB stick on step 3.

I tried with the 18.04.1 and the 12.04.5 releases, and I tried using Etcher (as in the tutorial) and UNetbootin to install the disk image on my USB.

I am using a mid-2014 Macbook Pro to prepare the USB stick.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! When you say it doesn't boot, does the mac attempt to boot it but it gives you a blank bootup screen? I.e., hold Cmd-C on power up and choose usb booting?

Comment: @BernardWei 
Thank you!
I mean that the USB doesn't appear as a boot option when holding the option key on power up (as seen [here](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/35/3/1535533424-img-6522-1.jpg)).
The macbook boots whitout any option when holding Cmd-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to boot from the USB using rEFInd.

I found rEFInd [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/). I installed it in the original OS on the Macbook6.1 by running the `install-refind` script.

More information about refind [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

Answer (score 0):

[UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) makes creating a bootable USB straight forward.

**Warning:** make sure all important data is safe before doing this!

- In UNetbootin, browse to your disk image, select your bootable drive and click ok and wait for the installer to finish.
- Turn off your computer and back on again while holding `Option`. Your bootable USB will appear as `UEFI`.
- Boot in and follow the default installer (selecting 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu').

Comment: I tried using UNetbootin to create a bootable USB.
The USB still does not appear when powering up my Macbook while holding `Option`.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Maybe, your system uses a different key to `Option`? Can you navigate to the USB in your file directory and see `squashfs`? Are you sure the installation completed?; it should take about 15 minutes.  Did you run unetbootin with su write privileges? There are a few different methods of creating a bootable USB, but I have found Unetbootin to be the most reliable/easy.